# Bitbake build fails because of a python function

Tags: yocto, rpm, bitbake

During execution of a bitbake command the task which builds rpm package fails because of a python function. I have been unable to determine what could cause this function to fail. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
    ERROR: perl-5.30.1-r0 do_package_write_rpm: Error executing a python function in exec_func_python() 
autogenerated:The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was: File: 'exec_func_python() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
0001: *** 
0002:do_package_rpm(d)     
0003:
File: '/srv/yocto/poky/meta/classes/package_rpm.bbclass', lineno: 712, function: do_package_rpm     
0708:     
0709:    # Build the rpm package!     
0710:    d.setVar('BUILDSPEC', cmd + \"\\n\" + cleanupcmd + \"\\n\")     
0711:    d.setVarFlag('BUILDSPEC', 'func', '1')
0712:    bb.build.exec_func('BUILDSPEC', d)     
0713:     
0714:    if d.getVar('RPM_SIGN_PACKAGES') == '1':
0715:        bb.build.exec_func(\"sign_rpm\", d)     
0716:}
File: '/srv/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 254, function: exec_func     
0250:    with bb.utils.fileslocked(lockfiles):     
0251:    if ispython:     
0252:            exec_func_python(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)     
0253:    else: *** 
0254:            exec_func_shell(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)     
0255:     
0256:    try:     
0257:        curcwd = os.getcwd()     
0258:    except:
File: '/srv/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 455, function: exec_func_shell     
0451:    with open(fifopath, 'r+b', buffering=0) as fifo:     
0452:        try:     
0453:            bb.debug(2, \"Executing shell function %s\" % func)    
0454:            with open(os.devnull, 'r+') as stdin, logfile: *** 
0455:                bb.process.run(cmd, shell=False, stdin=stdin, log=logfile, extrafiles=[(fifo,readfifo)])     
0456:        finally:     
0457:            os.unlink(fifopath)    
0458:     
0459:    bb.debug(2, \"Shell function %s finished\" % func)
File: '/srv/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/process.py', lineno: 184, function: run     
0180:     
0181:    if pipe.returncode != 0:     
0182:        if log:     
0183:            # Don't duplicate the output in the exception if logging it *** 
0184:            raise ExecutionError(cmd, pipe.returncode, None, None)     
0185:        raise ExecutionError(cmd, pipe.returncode, stdout, stderr)     
0186:    return stdout, stderr Exception: bb.process.ExecutionError: Execution of '/srv/yocto/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/perl/5.30.1-r0/temp/run.BUILDSPEC.35372' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. Looking at the log file I've noticed the following error right before the error that I've posted in the question:

`Deprecated external dependency generator is used!
    create archive failed: cpio: write
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.`

I've reached out to some developers in the yocto mailing list and one of them suggested to run 'strace' on the bitbake command. However, it produces way too much output so it's not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was happening because my `SECTION` variable in my recipe was empty (`SECTION`=""). I attributed any value to it, like `SECTION` = "a", and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that my system had some missing prerequisites defined here: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.3.3/ref-manual/system-requirements.html

Executing following command solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git diffstat unzip texinfo gcc build-essential chrpath socat cpio python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping python3-git python3-jinja2 libegl1-mesa libsdl1.2-dev pylint3 xterm python3-subunit mesa-common-dev
```